What is the name of this lesser known non-euclidean geometry
Taxicab geometry is one of the more well-known non-euclidean geometries used in board games and video games. However there is a type of non-euclidean geometry that somewhat approaches euclidean geometry and I was wondering if there is a name for it.
In taxicab geometry, diagonal movement is prevented, but in this geometry, every even diagonal movement 'costs' 2 movement instead of one. This rule-set comes from The Dungeon Master's Guide (5E 2014 Edition) and it made me wonder if there was a name for this type of geometry?
$$\begin{matrix}
    7&7&8&8&9&9&10&10\\
    6&6&7&7&8&8&9&10\\
    5&5&6&6&7&7&8&9\\
    4&4&5&5&6&7&8&9\\
    3&3&4&4&5&6&7&8\\
    2&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
    1&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
    0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\end{matrix}$$
Edit: I am going to do my best at defining a metric. This is my first attempt at doing something like this so do be a little patient with me.
Imagine a coordinate grid. In this coordinate grid you can travel between two nodes vertically, horizontally, or diagonally. The distance between any two nodes vertically, or horizontally is 1. The first time you travel diagonally the distance is 1. If you travel diagonally of distance 1 to a node, the very next time you travel diagonally to a different node the distance is increased to 2. If you were to again travel diagonally, the distance to a diagonal node is reduced to 1.
This metric also holds against the triangle inequality as the sum of traveling 1 horizontally and 1 vertically is greater than or equal to traveling either 1 or 2 diagonally.
I also see that my matrix might be confusing. The matrix simply describes the sum of the distance required to reach a node where the above definition applies.

Your definition of the metric is very unclear

@MoisheKohan In what way? The rule seems clearly stated but I suppose I can expound. The first and every odd diagonal movement $n$ is treated as only one movement. Every even diagonal movement $n$ is treated as two movements.

So it's taxicab geometry, but it forms an octagon? I would guess this is just a two dimensionally skewed version of the infinity norm, but I'm not even educated on this to answer the question.

This does not satisfy the triangle inequality:  $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(3,2)$ form a triangle with side lengths $1$, $2$ and $4$.

I hope it would not satisfy the triangle inequality as it is clearly non-euclidean. @Nate

@theREALyumdub It is almost a geometry in-between board game geometries like taxicab where diagonal movement is restricted, and board game geometries where diagonal movement is completely unrestricted. The movement is only restricted half of the time, and the geometry more closely approximates a circle.

You did not define a metric, at all.

@ZacharyZastrow I am agreeing with the other commenters on what little I know about metric spaces. The geometry requires a metric and it isn't clear from your example, as it isn't obvious. Maybe you are looking for an invariant, not a geometry.

While you have not told us quite what you mean by non-Euclidean geometry, your expectation that it would violate the triangle inequality is quite contrary to the meaning of non-Euclidean geometry that I am aware of. For example, the classical non-Euclidean geometry --- the one which, in the 19th century after two thousand years of research was, finally, constructed so as to violate the parallel postulate, nonetheless still satisfies the triangle inequality.

@LeeMosher My attempt is not to define a geometry, simply to ask if anyone knows of one that has rules similar to my informal description

@MoisheKohan I am not attempting to define a metric, I am giving an example and asking if anyone know something similar to the description. If I already knew the metric there would be no utility in asking the question.

@theREALyumdub If I knew more graph theory I would attempt to define the metric better, alas I am early in my mathematics learning. I believe I am looking for a geometry as it is typically compared to taxicab, but I have never heard any well defined nomenclature for this set of rules.

@ZacharyZastrow Comments are not for discussion, as that is the purpose of a forum, where as this is a question and answer site. Maybe you can look for an invariant of the space, but you have a problem on the diagonal.

@theREALyumdub The triangle inequality holds.

Based on Wikipedia for metric space, it sounds like you've described a "semi-metric" satisfying the "2-relaxed triangle inequality". (Even with a genuine metric, the phrase "non-Euclidean geometry" in not often used when discussing metric spaces.)

It is not a metric.
Consider this Example :

Moving two Squares along the Purple line will cost $1+2=3$ , which is the minimum (other ways might cost $1+1+1+1=4$)
Moving along the Blue line will cost $1$
Moving along the Green line will cost $1$
Hence with two moves , the cost is $1+1=2$
Thus the triangle inequality is broken :
$D(A,B)+D(B,C) \le D(A,C)$
We actually want :
$D(A,B)+D(B,C) \ge D(A,C)$
We have almost everything else other that that :
$D(A,A)=0$
$D(A,B)=D(B,A)$
Still , the triangle inequality is the crucial component.
Details :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space

Here is the issue, but in D&D terms:  Suppose you need to move $4$ squares to the right and $2$ squares up to get some loot, but you only have movement 2 (or movement 10 if each square is 5 feet like in D&D).
In 2 turns you can get there, by moving right one and diagonal up to the right one each time.  Paradoxically though, if you play the dash action to double your movement speed you can't actually reach there in one turn: that point 4 over and 2 up takes 5 movement to get to.
This sort of thing could not happen if this actually defined a metric, and having a metric is sort of a precursor for being a "geometry".
